# Why is t-sne considered supervised?

Tags: machine-learning, supervised-learning

What makes t-sne supervised?

Wikipedia classifies the [t-sne algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-distributed_stochastic_neighbor_embedding) as a supervised method. I read that supervised methods involve training, with an input and a desired result.

I was thinking, the goal of t-sne is to minimize the Kullback–Leibler divergence. Does minimizing this divergence count as a "desired result", which makes it supervised?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wikipedia does not classify t-sne as supervised learning but as dimensionality reduction (at the moment I am writing the answer). And, as far as I know, it is not a supervised method at all.

Its purpose is to ease the data visualization, reduce dimentionality and can also be used as a clustering technique (**unsupervised** classification).

Comment: Oh...oops. Looks like I was confused by the fact that the machine learning articles have a box on the side of the page listing the different categories of problems. I saw "supervised" as one of the categories and thought it was describing t-sne. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

t-sne plot can be a tool for comparison of Supervised vs unsupervised clustering datas.

Like this: https://youtu.be/5vrvsiVO00k

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34641571)